# Is there a way to do a git diff that allows me to switch between changed files at will?

Tags: git

I am doing a code review on a feature branch. The main develop branch has recently been merged in.

Using gitk, I can see changes in the series of commits on the feature branch. But I want to look at the final changes for each file, not changes on the same set of files that spans multiple commits.

Using `git difftool featureBranch…develop` I can get close to what I want. It shows the final differences between each changed file. The problem is, it awkwardly presents one file at a time in my difftool. I don't see a way to switch between files at will to do an effective code review.

I can get this behavior in a git GUI such as Tortoise Git, but I'd prefer to stick to the command line and a difftool if possible. I currently use KDiff3, but I'd be willing to try a different one. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I don't use the various diff tools, I just run `git diff`. That makes the diffs as plain-text—not as easy to view as side-by-side, but much easier to just page through the whole thing. It's far simpler than `git difftool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git difftool --dir featureBranch…develop
```

Provided your configured difftool supports it.